# c++11 share fixed size array between different classes

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm working with on real-time application divided in two parts (threads):

- processing
- graphics

the output of processing is an array of fixed size (of `float`) and to maintain a real-time performance I want to send such data to another thread that will draw, for example graphs, at its own pace. 
I've looked into `atomic` and `lock` but I can't figure out how to make the application thread-safe given that the two processes are completely independent.

Sample code:

```
class A {
    float data[n];
    processData() {
        data = ... ;
    }
}

class B {
    void draw() {
        // requires data[] from class A
    }
}
```

Both classes are initialized in the main thread and I've tried to define a `float*` pointer there and pass it to the other two threads, processing assigns it to `data[]` and graphics is able to read it but there's obviously errors when one is reading and the other is modifying it at the same time.

Comment: What is the size of the array?

Comment: it can vary (not at runtime), but usually it's 256, 512 or 1024

Comment: Side note: since you're using C++11, no need for "raw" arrays, there's [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: _two processes are completely independent_ process != thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a queue of your float values for the graphics output and a mutex.

Whenever the processing has generated some output, lock the common mutex, append the data to the queue, unlock the mutex.

On the other side, periodically lock the mutex from the graphics thread, see if there is new data to be displayed, if so then remove that data from the queue, temporarily copying it to a thread-local data buffer to ensure that the mutex is not locked while doing graphics output, and unlock the mutex right after the data is copied. Then display the graphics in that thread, using the local copy.

Comment: I'm unable to share a common mutex between different classes when I tried, mind posting a simple example?

Comment: What did you try? You can add your code to your question by editing it.

Comment: Why would you be unable to "share" a mutex? You only need one mutex variable that is accessed by both classes. You could for starters just declare a `std::mutex procMu` globally and use it from both your threads.

Comment: I haven't tried to declare it as a global variable but instead I passed it to both classes but that gives and error (can't be copied). As I'm writing this I'm realizing that it's obvious I can't copy it, should I pass it as a pointer?

Comment: You can either pass it as a pointer or reference, both work fine.

Comment: Note that this approach is going to get you in trouble if generating new data is faster than displaying it. Eventually you'll run out of memory. It also requires you to keep allocating memory again and again, since there's no way to reuse a buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use an [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) to prevent both threads from accessing the data at the same time.

Of course, that means only 1 thread at a time can do something with the data. If that is a bottleneck (i.e. you want to generate new data while drawing previous data), consider [double buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering). That way, both reading and writing can happen simultaneously. Note that you'll still need some sort of synchronization using e.g. a mutex to make sure the writer doesn't start writing into the buffer that's currently being used by the reader (or vice versa). You can improve on that by using triple buffering.

Comment: yes I'd like to continue processing data while drawing since the latter has lower priority and is easier to play with. Problem with double buffering is that the "refresh" rate of the two parts is different and can vary to 2x or 3x (e.g. processing data every 10ms and drawing a new frame each second). Would that still be possible?

Comment: @mastaH Yes, if you use triple buffering you can run both the reader & writer as fast as possible. You can find an example of code implementing this here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163810/lock-free-zero-copy-triple-buffer.